# Summation Problem and finding its Modulus, how could I tackle it?

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic

$$\sum _{i=2}^{63}\frac{i^{2011}-i}{i^2-1}\bmod 2016$$

How could I do this problem? I know I should be looking for patterns that relate to 2016 and it's multiples, but after that I'm confused.

Comment: $$\dfrac{n^{2011}-n}{n^2-1}=\sum_{r=0}^{1004}n^{2r+1}$$

Now $\displaystyle\sum_{n=2}^{63}n=\dfrac{62(63+2)}2\equiv-1\pmod{2016}$

Comment: could you explain the first equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Using summation formula of [Geometric Progression](https://brilliant.org/wiki/geometric-progressions/#geometric-progression-sum)
$$\dfrac{n^{2m+3}-n}{n^2-1}=\sum_{r=0}^mn^{2r+1}$$

$$\implies S=\sum_{n=2}^{63}\dfrac{n^{2m+3}-n}{n^2-1}=\sum_{n=2}^{63}\left(\sum_{r=0}^mn^{2r+1}\right)$$

Interchanging the order of summation,

$$S=\sum_{r=0}^m\left(\sum_{n=2}^{63}n^{2r+1}\right)$$

$$=\sum_{r=0}^m\left(\sum_{n=1}^{63}n^{2r+1}\right)-\sum_{r=0}^m1$$

Now $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{63}r=\dfrac{62(63+2)}2\equiv0\pmod{2016}$

Use [Show that $1^k+2^k+3^k+ \ldots +n^k$ is divisible by $ 1+2+3+ \ldots +n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470427/show-that-1k2k3k-ldots-nk-is-divisible-by-123-ldots-n)

$$\implies S\equiv-\sum_{r=0}^m1\pmod{2016}\equiv2016-(m+1)$$

Comment: omg thank you, I think I get it. I'll get back to you

Comment: ok I get it, so basically you separate the summation into a piece that you know is divisible by 2016 (so mod 2016 is just zero) and then it's "remainder" component which ends up being the answer

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{r=1}^{63}r=\frac {63(64)}2=2016\equiv 0\mod 2016$.