# Sum of $n$ $k$-th powers is a multiple of $n+1$?

Tags: number-theory

Is this statement valid?

"If $k$ is a positive odd number, then $1^k+2^k+· · ·+n^k$ is divisible by $n+1$"

I don't think so. Did I missed anything subtle? (given who wrote the book)

Source: [Solving Mathematical Problems](https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=4ieQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=If%20k%20is%20a%20positive%20odd%20number,%20then%201k%2B2k%2B%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%2Bnk%20is%20divisible%20by%20n%2B1&source=bl&ots=TILPbLUzTp&sig=ACfU3U0he9s-hgF8gOM3os7RjBZc7CO-aw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxntH_idv5AhUrk-YKHSEmDqYQ6AF6BAgjEAM#v=onepage&q=If%20k%20is%20a%20positive%20odd%20number%2C%20then%201k%2B2k%2B%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%20%C2%B7%2Bnk%20is%20divisible%20by%20n%2B1&f=false) by Terence Tao

[Relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470427/show-that-1k2k3k-ldots-nk-is-divisible-by-123-ldots-n).

Comment: I mean, did you try the case $k=1$?

Comment: yes I did that and it didn't work. Are you confirming that it is invalid?

If it was a misprint, what might be the intended statement?

Comment: It's not even close to valid.  The parity is wrong.  Take $n$ odd of the form $4m+1$.  Then the left hand is odd (for any $k$) but $n+1$ is even.

Comment: I suggest:  try to prove that the parity problem is the only obstruction.  That is to say, there are no counterexamples other than the (infinite) family I described.

Comment: You might want to look at this, which is the closest related thing I can think of: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9207222. You always get a polynomial of the case $k=1$, that is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.